# Is it possible to add a custom property into a style in an android resource?

Tags: android, styles

I'm a using a view flow component into my project, which allows the dev to override some attributes, like that :

```
<org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator
    ...
    app:footerTriangleHeight="0dip"
    ... />
```

I am reusing this component into several layouts, and I would like to put the properties into a style.
But when I'm doing this, the parser says `Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:footerTriangleHeight'`, even if I add the namespace in the styles file.

Is there a way to do that in android ?

Thanks.

Comment: Selected answer is wrong/incomplete. You can style custom UI elements in the style file, done this myself... See my answer for example

Comment: please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml) that will address your issue.

Comment: I found the same issue on SO and that addressed my problem,[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml)

Comment: [I found the same issue in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Android Application**

If you are not using Android Libraries, then here is what you can do:

1. Define custom styleable attribute (I guess you've already done that).
2. Do not use your namespace prefix in style items (namespace defaults to current app's namespace).

Example:

In *attrs.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="testAttr" format="string"/>        
</resources>
```

In *styles.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>        
    <style name="TestStyle" >
      <item name="testAttr">asdf</item>
    </style>        
</resources>
```

---

**Android Library**

If custom attribute comes from Android Library, you can still use described approach. It theoretically should work, because Android Library's namespace is the same as application's (from `aapt` tool perspective during the build). But I haven't test this myself.

---

If you're specifying namespace, it will show error. As far as I know, styles do not support xml namespaces. So this will fail:

In *styles.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/app.package.name">        
    <style name="TestStyle" >
      <item name="app:testAttr">asdf</item>
    </style>        
</resources>
```

Parser automatically defaults to current app's `AndroidManifest` namespace, though you can not specify this namespace explicitly.

Comment: You are right, I just needed to remove the namespace in the styles file, and it worked. But it's weird that it is needed in a normal layout file, and not in a resources file. Thanks.

Comment: This works with the new CardView widget for example: just remove the namespace, and a style item like <item name="contentPadding">16dp</item> compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can define the style in terms of your namespace, i've used it myself

i.e

```
<style name="whatever">
    <item name="YourPackage.YourSubPackage:parametername">@drawable_or_anything/bla</item>
</style>
```

Comment: For the text before the : use whatever namespace is defined in your manifest as your "package"

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My custom style attribute is an enum.

Comment: You tried to full quantify the enum as well as the attribute?

Comment: Can it be used to refer to a library view's property?