# Multiple fonts associated with same TextView

Tags: android

Is there any way to set different fonts for different states in a TextView? 
Let's say I want Helvetica Regular for normal state, and Helvetica Bold for pressed?

I know how to link a custom font with a text view, but not sure how to do same for multiple fonts and single TextView? Specifically, is there a way to achieve this behaviour through xml?

**Update**: I'm not looking into workarounds, like having HTML in TextView, or even replacing TextView with WebView. If it's not possible to achieve, I'd rather have one font

Comment: why you don't use webview and  font tag inside it

Comment: first of all, replacing textview with webview is an overkill. second, I have a huge app where all I need is to update fonts.

Answer (score 0):

check this link may help you:

http://shuklaxyz.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-fonts-for-webview-and-textviewv.html

also :

[Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)

also:

[Custom TrueType font from xml only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413572/custom-truetype-font-from-xml-only)

and this :

http://polwarthlimited.com/2013/05/android-typefaces-including-a-custom-font/

hope that help.

Comment: No it doesn't help as none of the links answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Using Html.fromHtml comes in handy, but it is limited to the tags you can use.  I personally only have used this to do Bold, Colors, italics.
Like this:

```
String myWords ="<FONT COLOR = "#992211">This is Red:</FONT><br>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myWords));
```