# Custom attributes with gradle in style

Tags: android, gradle

Hi,

I have one library project with custom attributes.

#### attrs.xml:

```
    <resources>
            <attr name="someCustomAttribute" format="integer" />
            <declare-styleable name="FirstView">
                    <attr name="someCustomAttribute" />
            </declare-styleable>
            <declare-styleable name="SecondView">
                    <attr name="someCustomAttribute" />
            </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

In my project I use that library and in styles.xml i have something like this:

#### styles.xml

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <style name="CoolStyle">
                  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
                  <item name="someCustomAttribute">42</item>
           </style>
    </resources>
```

When I'm trying to `gradle assemble` I got:

```
    ...
    <project>/build/res/all/release/values/values.xml:1421: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'someCustomAttribute'.
    <project>:processReleaseResources FAILED
    ...
```

or with `--stacktrace`:

```
 Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':<project>:<project>:processReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':<project>:<project>:processReleaseResources'
        at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 70 more
    Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        /home/mikhail/Tools/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/mikhail/Tools/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M <project>/build/bundles/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S <project>/build/res/all/release -A <project>/build/bundles/release/assets -m -J <project>/build/source/r/release -F <project>/build/libs/<project>-release.ap_ --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols <project>/build/bundles/release
    Error Code:
        1
    Output:
        <project>/build/res/all/release/values/values.xml:1421: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ptrAnimationStyle'.

        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:69)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:617)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processResources.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:71)
        at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
        ... 77 more
```

Gradle app setup files:

#### settings.gradle

```
    include '<Library>:<Library>'
    project(':<Library>:<Library>').projectDir = new File('/path/to/lib')
```

#### build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':<Library>:<Library>')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
    }
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Regards, Mikhail

Comment: how do you access the file in your .gradle file? Please show some code for this

Comment: I've added gradle setup information to the original question.

Comment: Mikhail, have you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I just put gradle aside for a while and resume to use maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:
I've put path to the different lib in my `settings.gradle`, feel so stupid...

Answer (score 1):

In your styles.xml do not specify the namespace. Instead add this.

```
<resources xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your_package_name">
       <style name="CoolStyle">
              <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
              <item name="someCustomAttribute">42</item>
       </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: That doesn't work :(
Neither with library package nor with app package.
Add prefix to attributes, doesn't help either. Like this:
`<item name="custom:someCustomAttribute">42</item>`

Comment: Did u try using Ricardo Rocha's answer along with mine? Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml) similar to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Would this help on attrs.xml file?

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomImageButton">
    <attr name="customAttr" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Doesn't help :( Same output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the first line of your attrs.xml from `<resources>` to 
`<resources "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">`

Comment: Doesn't work :(
Nor `<resources "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">`
Nor `<resources xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">`
Nor all above with `custom:` prefix in **styles.xml**