# Extract Support Library layout attributes into styles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-styles

I am extracting styles for views which are inside Support Library's `GridLayout`.

Therefore, I have both attributes from the "android" namespace, e.g. `android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"` and attributes from the "app" (http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto) one, e.g. `app:layout_columnSpan="2"`.

First, Android Studio doesn't recognize the attributes from "app" when I try to extract the attributes as a style. Second, it doesn't seem that extracting them into styles.xml manually brings any effect to the actual layout. So, is it possible to extract the Support Library attributes as a separate style, and how?

Comment: Are you using gradle build? Am I right that you have compilation error? Or Android Studio complaints/highlights these lines?

Comment: Yes, I am using Gradle build, and correct, there are compilation errors. I just noticed that the attributes are ignored in Design mode previously, but the result is nevertheless the same - "app" attributes are not working.

Comment: Did you add schema to your xml?

Comment: Which XML? If you mean the layout XML, I have been extracting the attributes out of a working file, so yes, the XML namespace has been defined there already. I have also tried the same thing in the styles XML, but without success.

Comment: In meantime, as this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml) has been answered, the custom attributes should have no namespace prefix and they will be recognized. That worked for me, so I am going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6868308/754439). The same solution worked for me.

Just leave out the namespace prefix for the non-"android" attributes:

`app:layout_columnSpan="2"` in the layout becomes

`<item name="layout_columnSpan">2</item>` in the styles, and **not**

`<item name="app:layout_columnSpan">2</item>`