# Using App namespace in style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am going to give an example to demonstrate the greater point.

Imagine my app has a number of FloatingActionButtons. Consequently, I want to create one style and reuse it. So I do the following:

```
<style name="FabStyle” parent ="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
    <item name="app:backgroundTint">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="app:layout_anchorGravity">end|bottom</item>
</style>
```

The problem I am having is that the code is not compiling because it is complaining about

```
Error:(40, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:backgroundTint'.
```

I tried bringing the namespace in through the `resources` tag but that is not working

```
<resources
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
```

Any ideas how I might get this to work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860886/custom-attributes-in-styles-xml/6868308

Answer (score 321, accepted):

For `app` namespace you don't need to specify `app:<property name>`. Just `<property name>` is enough.

### For example

```
<style name="FabStyle" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"> 
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="layout_anchorGravity">end|bottom</item>
</style>
```

And for `layout_anchorGravity` you need to set it in XML file where you are defining Floating action button.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for helping. Minor correction: you can define `layout_anchorGravity` on the style page as well. It works as `<item name="layout_anchorGravity">end|bottom</item>`

Comment: you saved the day! And the one to be defined locally is `layout_anchor`. +1!

Comment: Well, doing so solved the error mentioned by OP. Even text predictor for `styles.xml` suggests the properties; but somehow it's like these properties are not applied at all after building... I wonder why...

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use the property without `app`

```
<style name="FabStyle” parent ="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="layout_anchorGravity">end|bottom</item>
</style>
```